# How to add bullet to character of a docx file with poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been learning about how to write a .docx file with POI. But I have no idea about how to add bullet point to a Chinese character like this:

[image]

Using Microsoft Word
[image]

Comment: What shall be the meaning of this dot under the chinese characters? How do you produce this in Microsoft Word using the GUI?

Comment: You likely need to create two documents, one with a character without the emphasis mark and one with and then take a look at the contents of the two .docx files (they are actually zip-files and can be unzipped to read the XML format), then you may be able to find out how Word puts these into the format and thus be able to create these via the XWPF classes and the CT_... low-level framework of POI.